# Is it possible to open edge developer tool using selenium WebDriver using C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open the Edge Developer tool using Selenium WebDriver in C#. The code that I wrote opens up the browser but not opening the developer tool. Any help in resolving the issue is much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).SendKeys("I").Perform();
        actions.KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Perform();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `WebView2` control? It seems to be a better choice for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: Is it imperative that you can physically see the developer tool or is it sufficient if you can access the developer tools and it’s functionality via an API?

Comment: It's imperative when running the tests in browser stack and video is captured while the tests are running. so for slow loading site it's helpful to see the test to opening in console (network tab).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Test1()
{
    var options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.UseChromium = true;
    options.AddArgument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");

    IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
}
```